# Can't write and save a video file using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to process frames from a video stream, and it as a new video.

This is what I'm doing :

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Videos/output.mp4',fourcc, fps, (1080,1080))
```

I keep getting :

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x44495658/'XVID' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000020/' ???'
```

I think I'm using the wrong fourcc value... Which one should I use ? I've been trying a lot of them.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7.11 and OpenCV 3.1.0

Answer (score 22):

Define the codec and create VideoWriter object like this

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

Comment: It's best to post an answer with more than just code.

Comment: working c version for Ubuntu 16.04 ` outputVideo = cvCreateVideoWriter("/tmp/out.avi",CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', 'E', 'G'),25,imgSize,1);`

Comment: @JeffBridgman I just posted an answer below explaining the issue. Cheers

Comment: I am getting below error. - OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x4745504d/'MPEG' is not supported with codec id 2 and format 'mpegts / MPEG-TS (MPEG-2 Transport Stream)'. What I am doing wrong --- fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MPEG")
    writer = cv2.VideoWriter(outpath, fourcc, 30, (W, H), True)

Answer (score 7):

**For Windows users**

*I am using OpenCV 2 with Python 3.6, on Windows 10.*

The `'XVID'` codec, along with producing a `.avi` file, seems to be the most generic solution (if not the only one that works).

```
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv.VideoWriter('test.avi', fourcc, 60, (320, 240))
```

In addition, only `BGR` can be directly written with such a `VideoWriter` declaration. Don't try to write gray frames: the output would be empty.

Comment: And you need to revert the sizes of images if you read them from cv2.imread : 
`image        = cv2.imread(path_to_image) 
frameSize = (image.shape[1],image.shape[0])`

Comment: Regarding `BGR` writings, there is `isColor` parameter in [`VideoWriter`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ad59c61d8881ba2b2da22cff5487465b5) constructor, setting it to `False` enables to write gray

Comment: @Right this did not work for me on Ubuntu 18, OpenCV 3.4.3

Answer (score 7):

The problem that you are having is that you are trying to export the frames in `XVID` format but the name of your output file is ending with `.mp4`. You should change the export format to `MP4V` or the name of your output file to `.avi`.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Videos/output.mp4',fourcc, fps, (1080,1080))
```

alternative

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Videos/output.avi',fourcc, fps, (1080,1080))
```

here you can find more information about the [video codecs](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php)

Comment: (*'XVID') with '*.avi' is working, but if you want to create '*.mp4' -> ('m', 'p', '4', 'v') it worked in my Wind10 laptop. Interesting ...

Answer (score 3):

The size of the frame(width,height) you are giving, should match the size of the frame you want to save.
so
   `fw = int(cap.get(3))
 fh = int(cap.get(4))
 print("w,h",fw,fh) 
 out = cv2.VideoWriter('fb1.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D'), fps, (fw,fh))`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save video by opencv in mp4 format, let

Follow this [link](https://www.fourcc.org/fmp4/):

you should replace:

`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`

by:

`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'FMP4')`

I tried and succeeded.

Comment: I am using MacOS none of the answers worked for me but `*'FMP4'` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. With me, it turned out that I had switched the height and width of the video, so the frame dimensions did not match the video specifications and as a result nothing was written. Make sure they match exactly.

Also, OpenCV seems to give that same warning if the file extension does not match the codec used. Specifically, it wants .avi for the XVID codec.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to save as a .mp4, and using `*"mp4v"` turned out to be the right code, on Linux at least.

Check the example below

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
video = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, fps, (width, height))
```

Answer (score 1):

Install K-Lite Mega Codec Pack: https://filehippo.com/download_klite_mega_codec/  
This error occurs because some codecs are not available by default in Windows media player. So by installing this software, the video works fine with same code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux try this

fourcc = 0x00000021
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Videos/output.mp4',fourcc, fps, (1080,1080))

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i use:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, fourcc, FPS, (width,height))
```

and this work :>

Answer (score -2):

On a mac

`writer = cv2.VideoWriter('mysupervideo.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'mp4v'), 20, (width, height))`

Works better

Comment: that looks equivalent to existing answers.